# Does anyone know what this fan blower thingy is?

Tags: fans, blower

I initially thought it was some type of paint mixer then realized the end would not fit in a drill.

[image]

Comment: That end doesn’t seem good for much except hanging on a display hook. Perhaps that’s all it’s for? It looks unnecessarily difficult to clean as a paint mixer though.

Comment: See if you can pull the smaller plastic piece off. Perhaps you are meant to remove it to use the tool and replace it to store the tool.

Comment: The end piece does pull off.

Comment: That is a full-featured ruler.

Comment: @EricHauenstein Would have been nice to have numbers as well though.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Cyclone paint mixer.

[image: mixer image]

[Cyclone paint mixer](http://www.superiorindsupply.com/4066-red-devil-speed-demon-paint-mixer-adapts-to-any-500-1500-rpm-variable-speed-drill)

I imagine you just need to remove the hang tag at the drill end.

Comment: That's a bizarre use for a squirrel cage fan! I took apart an over-range microwave oven recently and found nearly the exact assembly inside, perhaps the convection air mover. Perhaps I should not have disposed of the fan assembly, but it was coated with condensed food fumes.

Comment: @fred_dot_u I wouldn’t really call it all that bizarre. Used (and sized) correctly, this type of design can actually ensure that essentially the entirety of the fluid in the container gets mixed (if used and sized correctly, it generates the same type of flow in a circular container as would be produced by convection currents).

Comment: This also works for whipping up frothy milkshaked

Comment: Can make one hell of a mess if not used correctly.

Comment: Do not use for whipping up milkshake after mixing paint.  Order of operations is important.